# Python: use of List Comprehensions in order to fill an empty list single object-by-single object

Tags: python, performance, optimization, list-comprehension

i have a 'dictionary-valueiterator' Groups. For each list of Groups i random sample two (or more values) and i store in a new list

```
GroupsList = list([])
  for m in Groups:
     GroupsList.append(point_random_selection(m,n))
```

where **point_random_selection**

```
def point_random_selection(list,n):
    if n == 0:
            raise TypeError("The pulse density 0 is not iterable")
    try:
        sample_point = random.sample(list,n)
    except ValueError:
        sample_point = list
    return sample_point

GroupsList = [[<liblas.point.Point object at 0x00000001363A0E10>],
 [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x00000002CE52CB38>],
 [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x00000000CF516908>],
 [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x00000004293F9400>],
 [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x0000000249F67C50>],
 [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x0000000312D85A90>],
 [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x000000047DF396A0>,
  <liblas.point.Point object at 0x000000047DF14F98>]]
```

where in some case i have two or more list (ex:)

```
GroupsList[6]
[<liblas.point.Point object at 0x000000047DF396A0>,
 <liblas.point.Point object at 0x000000047DF14F98>]
```

I wish to store one list-by-one list in the new list in order to append one-by-one also when i have two or more *liblas.point.Point object* as:

```
GroupsList = [[<liblas.point.Point object at 0x00000001363A0E10>],
     [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x00000002CE52CB38>],
     [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x00000000CF516908>],
     [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x00000004293F9400>],
     [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x0000000249F67C50>],
     [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x0000000312D85A90>],
     [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x000000047DF396A0>],
     [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x000000047DF14F98>]]
```

Is it a  List Comprehensions the best approach? ex to insert in

```
GroupsList.append(point_random_selection(m,n))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to change a nested list like `[[a, b], [c, d]]` into `[a, b, c, d]` using a list comprehension.  If that is the correct interpretation for what you are trying to do, the following will work:

```
GroupsList = [point for lst in GroupsList for point in lst]
```

However it would be better to just create the flat structure from the beginning by changing your loop to the following (replacing `append()` with `extend()`):

```
for m in Groups:
    GroupsList.extend(point_random_selection(m,n))
```

`a.extend(b)` (where `a` and `b` are lists) results in the same behavior as the following loop (but does it more efficiently):

```
for x in b:
    a.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I'm reading your question correctly, but are you looking for [`list.extend`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)? For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> a.extend([5, 1, 4])
>>> a
[1, 2, 5, 1, 4]
```

---

Also, some general style feedback:

- [Standard Python style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) strongly discourages naming variables things like `Group` or `GroupsList`; name them `groups` or `groups_list`.
- `list([])` is more easily written as just `[]`
- Naming the argument to `point_random_selection` `list` should probably be avoided, since it shadows the global `list()` function
- It seems like you could replace most of `point_random_selection` by

```
return random.sample(the_list, min(n, len(the_list))
```

Comment: Thanks Dougal, Python is so wide (and nice) and always surprising